# Can not connect to SQL Server instance in my PC

Tags: sql-server

I stopped SQL Server (`MSSQLSEVER`) and SQL Server Agent services and deleted the backup file and data file was located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL`. Log file is still there:

[image]

Now I can't connect to SQL Server

[image]

Can not start SQL Server (`MSSQLSERVER`) and SQL Server Agent services as well

Could you suggest me a solution to connect to my SQL Server instance?

Image of the error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do not have enough information to diagnose this issue.

However, I have two ideas of what you did.

1 - What you showed me in the picture is the data and log directories.  They contain all the system databases by default.  See image below.

If you have not done a shift delete of the files and directory, stop the sql server instance and recover them from the recycle bin and restart the sql server instance.

Be VERY careful when deleting directories.

If you do not have these files handy, you might have to re-install SQL Server.

2 - If you data files are in another directory, which I doubt.  Then, look in the windows event log and/or sql error log for errors.  Please post more details.

J

[image]

Comment: Is it allowed to unistall SQl server and re- install it to the same machine?

Comment: If this is a development or test box, go for it.  Otherwise, copy off the *.mdf, *.ndf, and *.ldf (database files) to another directory.  Uninstall, and reinstall.  You will have to attach the databases and re-create any orphaned accounts.  Here is a blog I did on databases files.  http://craftydba.com/?p=1753  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to connect to the SQL until the agent service is running again.
I think I need more information about what happens when you try to start the service.  Also, I'd probably (if possible) try to restart the machine.  Though that probably shouldn't be necessary, dependent on OS you're running it might help.
If you could post what happens when you try to start the service, that might be helpful.

Comment: I have add the image of the error messge. please be sorry i I have done any mistake since i am not familier that much with Stack Overfow

Comment: What happens when you try to start the SQL Agent service from Task Manager?  Does it generate some error message?

The other answer (From Crafty DBA) is probably correct in that you should, if possible, undo the changes you've recently done and try to restore where you were before.

Comment: ---------------------------
Services
---------------------------
Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 17113.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: The service:
SQL SERVER AGENT
Needs to be started first.  I'm not actually saying that is what is causing your problem, but, I believe you'll need to start that one first.  I'm not sure that they're linked together on your machine, so starting the SQL SERVER service prior to the SERVER AGENT may not load the AGENT service at all, which the SQL SERVER service is dependent upon.

Comment: ok..not it works after undo all the deletions, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is the SQL service running? The agent service is not required for connecting to an instance. To regain access to SQL server after deleting required files, read the following msdn article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.120).aspx